NGINX subdomain config causing too many redirect
I am having issue where my portfolio website which in on my domain works fine but the subdomain giving me too many redirects.
my config for therohankumar.com
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name therohankumar.com www.therohankumar.com;
    
    # Redirect all HTTP traffic to HTTPS
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;  # Using $host instead of $server_name
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name therohankumar.com www.therohankumar.com;
    
    # SSL configuration
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/therohankumar.com.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/therohankumar.com.key;
    
    
    # Enhanced security headers
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubDomains; preload" always;
    add_header X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN" always;
    add_header X-Content-Type-Options "nosniff" always;
    add_header X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block" always;
    add_header Referrer-Policy "strict-origin-when-cross-origin" always;
    
    # Optimization settings
    gzip on;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml application/json application/javascript application/xml+rss application/atom+xml image/svg+xml;
    
    # Root directory
    root /var/www/therohankumar;
    index index.html;
    
    # Enhanced location block
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        expires 30d;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, no-transform";
    }
    
    # Deny access to hidden files
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
        access_log off;
        log_not_found off;
    }
    
    # Optional: PHP configuration if needed
    #location ~ \.php$ {
    #    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    #    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    #}
}

My portal.therohankumar.com config
server {
  # Redirect any http requests to https
  listen         80;
  server_name    portal.therohankumar.com;
  return 301     https://portal.therohankumar.com$request_uri;
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
  default upgrade;
  '' close;
}

server {
  listen                    443 ssl;
  server_name               portal.therohankumar.com;

  # SSL certificates
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/therohankumar.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/therohankumar.com.key;

  # Proxy everything over to the GoCD server
  location / {
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header        Connection $connection_upgrade;
    proxy_pass              http://localhost:8153/;

    # To be able to upload artifacts larger than default size of 1mb, ensure that you set this up to a large value.
    # setting to `0` will disable checking for body size.
    # See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#client_max_body_size
    client_max_body_size  10000m;
    
    # If you are intending to allow downloading of large artifacts (> 1GB) from GoCD you may need to adjust one of the
    # following two proxy buffering settings to prevent downloads failing for slow clients due to server idle timeouts.
    #
    # See https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_buffering
    #
    # 1) disable the buffering of responses entirely (enabled by default on NGINX) OR
    # proxy_buffering off;
    #
    # 2) increase the max temporary file size (setting to `0` will disable the limit)
    # proxy_max_temp_file_size 2048m;
  }
}

I am not able to resolve it. Tried different thing use AI to find the mistake but no help
NOTE: I am using Cloudflare as my dns

Currently the redirect is not ALWAYS, so it is done also when requests are for portal.therohankumar.com.

What is your CloudFlare SSL mode (Off/Flexible/Full/Full (strict))?

It's Full(Strict). Thanks to @Luuk I was able to find the solution. It seems like I did not need to redirect to https since cloudflare was already doing it.
